# Different separators in the table

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, decimal

So i'm very new to R and I've managed to import my data (csv-file) and cleaned it, so it's manageable while using ggplot, by using this code:

```
#importing the file bergen_weather.csv into object and clean up the data in the table 
weather_bergen <- read_delim(file = "bergen_weather.csv",
                             delim = ";",
                             locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","),
                             col_names = c("name", "station", "date", "temperature", "precipitation"),
                             skip = 1, 
                             col_types = cols(date = col_date("%m.%Y"))) |>
  drop_na(date)
```

The problem is that only one of the columns (temperature) has dots as separators for the decimals while the other (precipitation) has commas, as seen in the picture of the table.

I would like to have all the data with dot-separators, but I'm unsure what code to use to get this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you could open the csv in notepad and paste the literal headers and first row as an example?

Comment: If you can provide an example of contant similar to the CSV file, it would be helpful